# the whole codding is correct but getting garbage value

Tags: visual-c++

The compiler is displaying garbage value when coded as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void summation(int value1,int value2, int sum)
{

    sum = value1+value2;

}
int main()
{
    int a,b,sum;
    cout<<"enter first no.\n";
    cin>>a ;
    cout<<"enter the second no.";
    cin>>b ;
    summation(a,b,sum);
    cout<<"the addition of two no. is :" <<sum ;
    return 0;
}
```

Obtaining correct input on writing &sum instead of sum. Why is it so?

Comment: You might want to rewrite the signature like `int summation(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}`

and call it like (in main): `sum = summation(a, b);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `sum` to the `summation()` method by value and you want to pass it by reference. Try defining your method like this:

```
void summation(int value1,int value2, int& sum)
{
    sum = value1+value2;
}
```

When you pass a parameter by its value (like you did), the method creates a copy of the value of the parameter and works with the copy. In the result, the passed parameter (`sum`) outside of the method stays unchanged. When you pass a parameter by its reference ( `int& sum` ), the `sum` variable inside your method will be the same as the `sum` variable in your `main` method and you can make changes to it.